# Youtube resumable upload 400 bad request

Tags: rest, file-upload, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to do a resumable upload to youtube using rest api clients.
STEP-1:

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status,contentDetails

Headers

```
Authorization        Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UxUBz459k8HO_gropj2SW6ShlFsqBqJMXI3HVfcE4lKWkR-gq4_Tj0j6Oqb-oo_qnE
Content-Length       278
Content-Type         application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Length  1393167
x-upload-content-type    application/octet-stream
```

Body

```
{
  "snippet": {
    "title": "My video title",
    "description": "This is a description of my video",
    "tags": ["cool", "video", "more keywords"],
    "categoryId": 22
  }
}
```

I get a 200 Ok response. I will the extract the url which is used in further request.

STEP-2:

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status,contentDetails&upload_id=AEnB2UqmDFhqQrOpbIgMp_E_bB6A3nP_Xb-DSiPHDUZRhz7usYMniFNASYeKoNrAktyPeXWLbLuz4fj1dUkaWg9cy9HQc-uKWA

Headers

```
Authorization        Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UxUBz459k8HO_gropj2SW6ShlFsqBqJMXI3HVfcE4lKWkR-gq4_Tj0j6Oqb-oo_qnE
Content-Length       1393167
Content-Type         application/octet-stream
```

Body

VideoFile - abcd.mp4

When i try to upload the file, it returns a 400 with the following response.

```
{
error: {
errors: [1]
0:  {
domain: "global"
reason: "badRequest"
message: "Invalid Upload Request"
}-
-
code: 400
message: "Invalid Upload Request"
}-
}
```

I tried to run the above request from various client - Advanced REST API client and Postman REST client of Google chrome, Java Program - everywhere it returns a 400. Can anyone please point out to what mistake i am doing in step2. It would be really helpful.

Comment: I get the same response. Have you found a solution?